# Using mruby, ngx_mruby and redis - Applying on current production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, ssl, nginx, redis

I am very afraid of making some modifications on the server. Because the server is working fine with the current settings.

I will to explain: The server is an **Amazon EC2** instance. In this instance I have:

```
ruby -v: ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-linux]
rails -v: Rails 4.2.3
nginx -v: nginx/1.8.0
passenger -v: Phusion Passenger version 5.0.10
```

I have 1 Load Balancer, which has a listner:

```
Load Balancer Protocol: HTTPS
Load Balancer Port: 443
Instance Protocol: HTTP
Instance Port: 80
SSL Certificate: Using a certificate issued on Amazon Certificate Manager. I have the domain and all sub-domains (wildcard).
```

This settings allow me to:

- Have the main domain to the app:

  - `www.testname.com` and `testname.com` to use as institutional pages (About, Price, Terms etc.);
  - `app.testname.com` for users to use the system;
- Have how many subdomains I want, because EACH USER has an specific page:

  - `user1.testname.com`
  - `user2.testname.com`
  - `user3.testname.com`
  - etc.

All work is dynamic. The user registers on the app and has a subdomain. In this subdomain, the user can access via `https://`. It works fine.

Users WANT to use their own domain, off course. This part is easily resolved. I create a CNAME record in the custom domain, pointing to the our subdomain, like that:

```
usercustomname.com    CNAME TO    user1.testname.com
```

It works fine. BUT, the big problem is: 'https://' not working on its custom domain name, obviously. Our certificate allows the domain `testname.com` and its subdomains.

With **Amazon Certificate Manger** I can import custom certificates. And then, using the awesome [rails-letsencrypt gem](https://github.com/elct9620/rails-letsencrypt), I can generate Let's Encrypt certificates to the custom domain names.

But the Amazon Load Balancer, in the `https listner`, allow to use only 1 certificate! This is very bad, because I can to have a lot of certificates, but using only one in the whole server.

Recently, [Amazon releases](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/aws/new-application-load-balancer-sni/) multiple certificates to `Application Load Balancer` using SNI. I can to migrate my `Classic Load Balancer` to the `Application Load Balancer`, but this not solves the problem, because the max certificates limit is 25 per Load Balancer. Is very low.

The solution I found is to create an [Amazon Elasticache](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/?nc1=f_ls) to run a REDIS server. And then, using [ngx_mruby](https://github.com/matsumotory/ngx_mruby) to get the certificate. I plan it like that:

- Change the `https listner` like that:

  - Instance Protocol: HTTPS
  - Instance Port: 443
  - Remove the certificate issued in Amazon Certificate Manger
- Install mruby
- Install [ngx_mruby](https://github.com/matsumotory/ngx_mruby)
- Using [rails-letsencrypt gem](https://github.com/elct9620/rails-letsencrypt), create 1 certificate for each institutional subdomain (app, www, *empty subdomain*) AND create 1 certificate for each user subdomain.

When a certificate is created, the `rails-letsencrypt gem` can save the certificate in REDIS.

Using `ngx_mruby`, listen the port 443, the certificate for the domain is picked up on redis.

Apparently, this will work. The logic seems right but I do not know in practice.

My questions are:

1) To install mruby, I will follow [these steps](http://ruby-doc.org/core-mruby/INSTALL.html). After install, **will impact in the current ruby installation?** Will I need to change the system code already developed as a mruby installation result?

2) **Using REDIS will affect something in the current server?** Despite the $ 12/month increase in Amazon's account, I believe that using REDIS will not influence the current server at all.

3) Do you think that what I planned to solve the Amazon certificate limit will works?

Sorry the big text. I'm not server specialist. This is the unique server I have, AND without backup. And I'm afraid to break the server with no way to fix.

Tks and I appreciate any help :)

### EDIT 1

Using `ngx_mruby` and `redis` with Amazon Classic Load Balancer will not works, beacuse the listner `https` requires one certificate. So even if I generate the certificates and connect ngx_mruby with redis, before it, the Load Balancer will respond with the default domain certificate.

But, I found a way (it works):

All customers URL have this structure:

- customer1.myapp.com
- customer2.myapp.com
- customer3.myapp.com

All requisitions are using `https` listner via Load Balancer and has no way to using multiple ssl certificates in classic load balancer. Then, I did:

- Register another domain, like `myapp.net`
- Using Amazon Route 53, I created another hosted zone and I point the domain DNS records to this hosted zone
- In Amazon Route 53, I created these records:

  - Type `A` point to the instance IP
  - Type `CNAME` with name `*` and value `myapp.net`

I setup my Rails App to identify the domain `myapp.net`. With this, the access to `customer1.myapp.com` AND `customer1.myapp.net` calls the same resource, **BUT**, `customer1.myapp.com` uses the lister `https` in the load balancer and `customer1.myapp.net` don't.

I just save the SSL CERTIFICATE which was generated by the gem in the folder `/etc/nginx/ssl/` and then, create a virtual host in NGINX. After that, FINALLY WORKS!

Now, I have to dicover HOW TO SAVE the certificate in the folder and HOW TO CREATE a virtual host in NGINX, using RAILS. The manual process is described in my [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51194043/how-to-save-a-ssl-certificate-and-create-a-virtual-host-in-nginx-using-a-rails-a).

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to recompile your Nginx to support ngx_mruby, we didn't suggest using dynamic module feature now. Because there is no use case with it when people using ngx_mruby. And your ruby version in your system didn't be changed.
2. If you want to enable Redis as the cache for your Rails, it may influence your website. But if you only create a new ElasticCache instance, there no other side effect for you. And I think to use ElasticCache you will get better optimize than host it by yourself.
3. I didn't try it, but it may work. Maybe others can answer your question.

Comment: Hello @Aotoki, thanks your answer. I will test in Heroku. After that, if all works fine, I will do this in Amazon. I will update this question ASAP.

Comment: Hey @Aotoki, after test, this solution doesn't works, because Amazon Load Balancer don't allow the HTTPS listner without one certificate. So even if I made the modifications, the Load Balancer still call the same unique certificate. Now, I have other way, that works! I will update this question!