# How to save a SSL certificate and create a virtual host in NGINX using a Rails App?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, ubuntu-14.04

I have a Rails app, which uses the [gem Rails Let's Encrypt](https://github.com/elct9620/rails-letsencrypt) to generate SSL certificates for custom domains.

The gem is really simple to use. After the installation/configuration, I can generate a certificate and the data will be stored in the database.

I want to save the `certificate CRT` and the `certificate KEY` in the respective NGINX folder: `/etc/nginx/ssl/`

After that, I want to :

- Copy the file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` and save with name `/etc/nginx/sites-available/customdomain.com`
- Change the file `customdomain.com` with this:

Content:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.customdomain.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/customdomain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/customdomain.key;
    passenger_enabled on;
    root /home/ubuntu/myapp/current/public;
    gzip on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    location ^~ /assets/ {
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
    }
}
```

- Create a link to this file in `sites-enabled` with this code: `sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/customdomain.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`
- Restart nginx: `sudo service nginx restart`

I did these steps manually and the SSL works fine. **How to do this programmatically?**

Remember, the steps starts when, with Rails, I generate a certificate. There must be some way to execute these steps. I appreciate any help! Tks!

My environment:

```
ruby -v: ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-linux]
rails -v: Rails 4.2.3
nginx -v: nginx/1.8.0
passenger -v: Phusion Passenger version 5.0.10
Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Amazon EC2 instance (without load balancer, because LB requires only one certificate in the https)
```

### EDIT 1

Perhaps, there's a way using wildcard configuration. Rather than create one virtual host for each domain, I create only one file, like that:

`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/wildcard`

In this file, I have a modification like that:

```
server_name {{customdomain_url}};
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/{{customdomain}}.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/{{customdomain}}.key;
```

If it is possible, is better, because the job is only save the certificate files. **And will not require the nginx restart**.

### EDIT 2 - The way

I created a shell script in `/user/local/bin/myscript.sh` and, in this script, I create a vhost file in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` to test. In `rails console`, I run the code: `sudo /user/local/bin/myscript.sh mydomain.com` and the shell script create correctly the file.

It was a test, but works. I will to create the final version and post here the final solution.

Comment: `will not require the nginx restart.` Except it will, if you think Nginx is checking that folder each time it serves a request and reloading it's configuration then you are mistaken. Config is loaded at runtime. You can't add servers on the fly. There are also several pitfalls in Nginx with different methods of trying to serve several domains over SSL from a single IP address, see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html

Comment: Hello @miknik, my app generate pages, that can be accessed with custom domains. Do you have some recomendation to me? I don't know how serve pages in 1 app to many domains. The pages is generated by the same app in the same server. I'm using Amazon EC2. This solution maybe is not the ideal, but is the unique that works...

Comment: @miknik This comment `will not require the nginx restart` is only if theres a way to do a wildcard vhost. Because the vhost was already launched. It will only get the certificate based in the domain (variables within vhost)

Comment: How wild do you want your wildcard to be? SSL certificates can only do a single level of wildcarding. So if you had a wildcard cert for `*.example.com` you could use it for `wild.example.com` and `card.example.com` but not `wild.card.example.com` or plain old `example.com`

Comment: Subdomains are working fine. The custom domains are the problem. I want 1 vhost file (wildcard) and in this vhost, the server name and the certificates (CRT & KEY) are variables, based in the domain. Is that possible?